# Reduce total blocking time on mobile due to google ads

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, web-vitals

The score of my mobile website in google page insight is very poor because of google ads
I only got 25 points while on desktop I got 77 points.

How can I reduce the total blocking time for my mobile site without lazy loading the third party script?

We are using cdn.thisiswaldo.com/static/js/7475 script to call google ads.

I also did lazy load google ads using this script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
        else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
  </script>
```

here's the Lab Data for mobile:

> First Contentful Paint
> 2.6 s
>
> Speed Index
> 14.3 s
>
> Largest Contentful Paint
> 7.6 s
>
> Time to Interactive
> 14.5 s
>
> Total Blocking Time 990 ms
>
> Cumulative Layout Shift
> 0.084

here's the Diagnostic
[Diagnostic Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXFgn.png)

below is the lists of third party ads that block the loading of the site.
[Blocking Third party code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb1Oy.jpg)

Comment: i had the same problem , but i solved it by removing the ads completely. unless you have  way to overpower google JS ad code. - just a suggestion

Comment: What is your reasoning for not deferring the Google Ads bootstrap?

Comment: the client client does not want to have ads delay because that's where they get the revenue.

Comment: Im just wondering why would be only the mobile be affected of slow website loading?

Comment: I know its old Willy, is your code being used in an external or in the main html file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the defer attribute to postpone executing the script until after the page has finished parsing.

See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Even when I defer the script my site only scored 46. https://pasteboard.co/JzwWs1p.png <link rel="preload" href="//cdn.thisiswaldo.com/static/js/7475.js" as="script">
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.thisiswaldo.com/static/js/7475.js"></script>